# Puppet have a defined resource fail if a variable is set to undef

Tags: puppet

I am writing a puppet defined type as follows:

```
  1 #--------------------------------------------------#
  2 #-------------------WindowsLog---------------------#
  3 #--------------------------------------------------#
  4 #           Type to set up a windows log           #
  5 #--------------------------------------------------#
  6
  7 define windows_log($size = '25MB', $overflowAction = 'OverwriteAsNeeded', $logName = $title)
  8 {
  9
 10     #Microsoft is stupid. Get-WinEvent has different names for logmode than limit-eventlog.
 11     #The following selector (basuically a ternary operator) should fix that
 12     $overflowWinEventName = $overflowAction ? {
 13         OverwriteAsNeeded   => "Circular",
 14         OverwriteOlder      => "AutoBackup",
 15         DoNotOverwrite      => "Retain",
 16         default             => undef,
 17     }
 18
 19     if($overflowWinEventName == undef)
 20     {
 21         fail("${$overflowAction} is not a valid overflow action")
 22     }
 23     else{
 24         exec { "Set maximum log size for ${logName}":
 25             provider => powershell,
 26             command  => "Limit-EventLog -LogName ${logName} -MaximumSize ${size} -OverflowAction ${overflowAction}",
 27             unless   => "\$log = Get-WinEvent -ListLog ${logName}; if(\$log.MaximumSizeInBytes -eq ${size} -and \$log.LogMode -eq '${overflowWinEventName}'){exit 0}else{exit 1}",
 28         }
 29     }
 30 }
```

However the method 'fail' does not have the effect I want, and none of the methods listed at http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html seem to be right either.

Basically I am trying to get puppet to throw an error for this specific resource only, stop applying it, and then continue applying everything else. Fail throws a parser error which kills everything, and the other methods (warn, error, etc) seem to have no effect on the agent.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I may have just stupidly overlooked something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your construct is basically sound. Defined resources cannot really 'fail' like native resources, but using your `if/else` construct, it will only do any work if there is no error.

Use `fail()` only if you detect an error that should make the whole catalog invalid. To just send a message to the agent, use a `notify` resource instead.

```
notify {
    "FATAL - ${overflowAction} is not a valid overflow action":
        loglevel => 'err',
        withpath => true; # <- include the fully qualified resource name
}
```

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I didn't realize I could set the log level on notify.

Comment: You know, I never tried that before making this answer, either ;-)